# Экранирование html тегов, Highcharts

Tags: html, highcharts

Как можно экранировать текст в html'е, чтобы он на странице воспринимался не как html, а как текст?
Тег `<plaintext>` не подходит, так как он "действует до конца кода веб-страницы, включая закрывающие теги `</body>` и `</html>`".

**UPD**

Html-текст работает с библиотекой **Highcharts**, и поэтому замену спецсимволами игнорирует...

Comment: а тег [xmp](http://htmlbook.ru/html/xmp) подойдет? он считается устаревшим хотя должен поддерживаться браузерами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<p>Можно заменить спецсимволами: 
  <code>&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</code> 
</p>
```